# How to schedule a task and maintain log history in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, quartz-scheduler, job-scheduling

Schedule to Run batch file and maintain execution history in logs and save into database using jsp/servlet. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid doing complex operation like database updates in a JSP.  These days, it is well understood that scriptlets are a bad idea:
      - [Disadvantages of using scriptlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21983369/disadvantages-of-using-scriptlet)
      - [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-file) s

For something like this, you want to use a servlet to do all of the complicated logic of scheduling tasks, tracking history and updating databases.  (But by all means use JSPs to render the HTML pages used to display the status / resukts / whatever of various operations.)

Once you have gotten past the correct choice of technology, what you are trying to do is just a matter of learning how to use quartz, and then designing the "workflow" for submitting, scheduling and reporting jobs.  In other words, the kind of thing that a Java programmer should be able work out for him / herself.